# How do I use Java on Spyder IDE?

Tags: java, spyder

I have downloaded both Java and Spyder IDE on my laptop. I heard that Spyder can support Java but I have no idea how to change its default language from Python to Java. Any help please?

I want to see some clear instructions on how to change Spyder's programming language.

Comment: "I heard that Spyder can support Java" - citation needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install install-jdk
```

or

```
pip install jdk4py
```

You will need to restart kernel to use updated packages.

After restart then import in `spyder` like one does when using `numpy` or `pandas`.